# Powermock java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available

Tags: junit, powermock, easymock

I am trying to mock a static Method in a class.

```
PowerMock.mockStatic(WebUtils.class); 
EasyMock.expect(WebUtils.getRequest(EasyMock.anyObject(Object.class))).andReturn(httpServletRequest).anyTimes();
PowerMock.replayAll();
```

`getRequest` is a non final static method. On the 2nd line, JUnit throws up below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:520)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:498)
    at --
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
```

Powermock version :1.6.2 & Running test class with PowerMockRunner.h

Comment: Do you have @PrepareForTest annotation?

Comment: Yes. I was giving the wrong class there. After giving WebUtils.class in @PrepareForTest, it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Good that it works now. Thus I added the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you set properly `@PrepareForTest` annotation.